# What is wrong with this iOS animation block?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

```
+ (void) AnimateSwitchingWithParent: (UIViewController *) ParentController From: (UIViewController *) From To: (UIViewController* ) To {

To.view.frame = ParentController.view.bounds;

[UIView transitionFromView:From.view toView:To.view 
        duration:1 
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];

ParentController.view = To.view;

[To viewWillAppear:true];
}
```

this is my function to make animation that will be called if want to change view from 1 view to another view, but I have problem, I have a viewController named filter, at there I have Button called Reset that will reset all of content inside
but to show that the reset have done, I want to call

[self AnimateSwitchingWithParent:self From:self To:self];

but the result is My View was blank. how can it be? any one have another way?

Comment: PLEASE start using naming conventions, i.e. correct upper and lower case. It makes reading and understanding code so much easier (and prevents bugs as well).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to flip the current view controller's view while resetting content, use the `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method.

**Example**

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^(void) {
                    [self resetStuff];
                } 
                completion:nil];
```

**Side Note**

You current implementation in the question will be useful to switching views in the view hierarchy. Say `From.view` is the subview of `ParentController.view` then the statement below will replace `From.view` with `To.view` as the subview of `ParentController.view`.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:From.view toView:To.view 
    duration:1 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
```

You definitely don't need to do this,

```
ParentController.view = To.view;
```

Doing that will replace the `ParentController`'s `view` which might be different from what you intended and definitely in contradiction to the transition animation on the line before.

You must definitely not be calling,

```
[To viewWillAppear:true];
```

directly.

To my understanding you should be able to remove the last two lines.